# How to pass bunch of elements as an argument in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I am trying to pass an array in R as an argument such that specific elements can be called at specific locations.
A sketch I have in mind is

```
labels = c("Direction","Lag1","Lag2",...,"Lagn")
model = function(DATA, elements,...){
   ....
   glm.fit = glm(elements[1]~elements[2]+....+elements[n+1], data=DATA)}
```

An example of required output is

```
labels = c("Direction","Lag1","Lag2","Lag3","Lag4")
model(file, labels) 
#^^^^ This should attempt to calculate 
#glm.fit = glm(Direction~Lag1+Lag2+Lag3+Lag4, data=file)
```

Now in this implementation, I am struggling through two problems.

1) The only way I can create an array containing features is if I keep them in string form. Whereas in the function I need them in variable form.

2) Since the length of labels is arbitrary (I plan to use the same model with different datasets and thus the length of the array will change), I need some mechanism in which the plusses in between can be written automatically (since the number of plusses present also depend on the length of labels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reformulate()` function is what you need!

```
mylabels = c("Lag1","Lag2","Lag3","Lag4")
myresponse = "Direction"
reformulate(mylabels, myresponse)
```

> Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the formula object for the linear model by pasting together the elements of `elements` yourself:

```
glm.fit = glm(as.formula(
              paste(elements[1], paste(elements[2:length(elements)], 
              collapse = "+"), sep =" ~ ")), data = DATA)
```

A working example:

```
data(iris)
labs <- names(iris)
glm(as.formula(paste(labs[1], paste(labs[2:length(labs)], collapse = "+"), sep =" ~ ")), data = iris)

Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(paste(labs[1], paste(labs[2:length(labs)], 
    collapse = "+"), sep = " ~ ")), data = iris)

Coefficients:
      (Intercept)        Sepal.Width       Petal.Length        Petal.Width  
           2.1713             0.4959             0.8292            -0.3152  
Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
          -0.7236            -1.0235  

Degrees of Freedom: 149 Total (i.e. Null);  144 Residual
Null Deviance:      102.2 
Residual Deviance: 13.56    AIC: 79.12
```

Answer (score 1):

We can write a function to handle variable arguments

```
fun_model <- function(data, response, predictor, ...) {
   formula <- paste0(response, "~", paste0(c(predictor, c(...)), collapse = "+"))
   glm(as.formula(formula), data = data)
}

fun_model(mtcars, "mpg", "cyl", "am", "gear")


#Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(formula), data = data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl           am         gear  
#     38.787       -2.555        3.890       -1.212  

#Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
#Null Deviance:     1126 
#Residual Deviance: 262.4   AIC: 168.1

fun_model(mtcars, "mpg", "cyl")

#Call:  glm(formula = as.formula(formula), data = data)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)          cyl  
#     37.885       -2.876  

#Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
#Null Deviance:     1126 
#Residual Deviance: 308.3   AIC: 169.3
```

Comment: Can you tell what to do if I need to use an element of the predictors in the function, like pass a command as am[25]? predictor[i][25] doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @mathnoob123 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean? `predictor` is a character input to the function. Do you mean something like `names(mtcars)[9]` ?

Comment: For example, you take "cyl" as an input in the function. It is possible that cyl is also an array. How would I call something like cyl[5] in the function? Precisely, say labels = c("x","y") and x is an array. How would I tell the function to access x[25]?

Comment: @mathnoob123 You can pass `x[25]` directly or if it is stored as a character vector like `labels`, you can do `get(labels[1])[25]`. So maybe `fun_model(data, "response", get(labels[1])[25])`

Comment: And say, I want to do the same thing like the "+" but this time instead I am trying to do with cbind(get(labels[1]),get(labels[2]),....). How would I tell the function to code that provided the labels array containing strings?

Comment: @mathnoob123 `paste0(get(labels[1]),get(labels[2]), collapse = "+")`

Comment: No no. Thats not I mean. For example: ```label = ["x1","x2",...,"xn"]; fun_model = function(label){ return( cbind(get(label[1]),get(label[2]),....,get(label[n])}``` Now in my original post, I could have just collapsed with a "+", but over here, I can't collapse it with something like "get".

Comment: No need to use `cbind` here. You can do `paste(get(labels[1]), get(labels[2]), get(labels[3]), sep  = "+")`

Comment: No, I was asking for a different hypothetical situation just to get an intuition for this technique

Answer (score 0):

For (generalized) linear models with only marginal terms, this is also sufficient:

```r
## mpg ~ cyl + am + gear
glm(mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "am", "gear")])
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl", "am", "gear")])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          cyl           am         gear  
#>      38.787       -2.555        3.890       -1.212  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  28 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       1126 
#> Residual Deviance: 262.4     AIC: 168.1

## mpg ~ cyl
glm(mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")])
#> 
#> Call:  glm(formula = mtcars[c("mpg", "cyl")])
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)          cyl  
#>      37.885       -2.876  
#> 
#> Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  30 Residual
#> Null Deviance:       1126 
#> Residual Deviance: 308.3     AIC: 169.3
```